# Magento 2.1.7 Adding additional category custom attribute not saving

Tags: custom-attributes, magento-2.1.7

I am attempting to add an additional category custom attribute to an existing module. A previous developer had already added two custom attributes and I am working on adding a third. I am able to get the third custom attribute to display in the backend but when I save any value inside the field, the new custom attribute does not save but I am able to modify the two existing custom attributes.

Any assistance to resolve this issue is appreciated.

InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace WholeLatteLove\CategoryMedia\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

/**
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
/**
 * EAV setup factory
 *
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Init
 *
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    /**
     * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
     */

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'header_img',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Header Image',
            'input' => 'image',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 5,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'General Information',
        ]
    );

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'youtube_id',
        [
            'group' => 'General Information',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'YouTube ID',
            'input' => 'text',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Varchar',
            'sort_order' => 5,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
        ]
    );

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'cinematic_img',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Cinematic Image',
            'input' => 'image',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 5,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'General Information',
        ]
    );

    }
}
```

category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="catvideoattribute">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Youtube ID</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="youtube_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Youtube Video ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>

<fieldset name="headerimgattribute">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Header Image</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">101</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="header_img">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Header Image</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>

<fieldset name="cinematicimgattribute">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cinematic Image</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">102</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="cinematic_img">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cinematic Image</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved. Since the module was already installed, I had to update the module by using a UpgradeData.php file. I removed the new custom attribute from the Install.php file and placed it into a new UpgradeData.php file.

I also needed to update the composer.json and module.xml file with a new version number.

Without using the UpgradeData.php, the database schema was not updating and that was why the new attribute values were not saving.

InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace WholeLatteLove\CategoryMedia\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\{
ModuleContextInterface,
ModuleDataSetupInterface,
InstallDataInterface
};

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
/**
 * EAV setup factory
 *
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Init
 *
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    /**
     * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
     */

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'header_img',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Header Image',
            'input' => 'image',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 5,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'General Information',
        ]
    );

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'youtube_id',
        [
            'group' => 'General Information',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'YouTube ID',
            'input' => 'text',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Varchar',
            'sort_order' => 5,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
        ]
    );


  }
}
```

UpgradeData.php

```
<?php

namespace WholeLatteLove\CategoryMedia\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\{
ModuleContextInterface,
ModuleDataSetupInterface,
UpgradeDataInterface
};

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
/**
 * EAV setup factory
 *
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Init
 *
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    /**
     * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
     */

    if ($context->getVersion() && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.0') < 0) {

      $eavSetup->addAttribute(
          \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
          'cinematic_img',
          [
              'type' => 'varchar',
              'label' => 'Cinematic Image',
              'input' => 'image',
              'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
              'required' => false,
              'sort_order' => 5,
              'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
              'group' => 'General Information',
          ]
      );

    }

    $setup->endSetup();

  }
}
```

category_form.xml is same as above.

composer.json

```
{
  "name": "wholelattelove/categorymedia",
  "description": "N/A",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "WholeLatteLove\\CategoryMedia\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="WholeLatteLove_CategoryMedia" setup_version="1.1.0">
         <sequence>
             <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
         </sequence>
     </module>
 </config>
```

Comment: This is not working. Can you please double check the code you have provided?

Comment: Can you clarify the issue you are having?